# PHP variable into Python

Tags: php, python, variables

I understand there are questions like mine already asked, but I can't figure this out even with the answers in those questions.

PHP:

```
<?php
$var1 = "hi";
$result = shell_exec('TestingStuff.py'.$var1);
?>
```

Python:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

Error received when running in Python:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Both scripts are in the same folder.

Could someone please provide an answer with the code changes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "both scripts are in the same file"  Do you have a single text file where you want parts of it to be php and parts of it to be python?  Also, I think you need a space after TestingStuff.py in your `shell_exec` line

Comment: @EricRenouf Apologies - I mean 'folder'. Where do you mean a space?

Comment: `shell_exec('TestingStuff.py ' . $var1)`

Comment: You can execute a python program by have `python TestingStuff.py args` and not `TestingStuff.py args`

Comment: @JensA.Koch Thanks but I get the same error

Comment: @BhargavRao Could you please write exactly how the code would be?

Comment: I tried now and surprisingly, it works without python too. Will write an answer if I get a break through

Comment: Wouldn't sys.argv[0] be your parameter?

Comment: Do you not need a space between the name of your file & the arg?

Comment: @jens sometimes things need an explanation.

Comment: @Toby You are right. I've added an explanation, which addresses some of the issues raised.

Comment: @Morgan sys.argv[0] is always the script name.

Answer (score 2):

**Error**

If the Python script runs with no arguments at all, then that `sys.argv[1]` index is out of range.

**Scripts**

`ExecPython.php`

```
<?php
$var1 = "hi";
$result = shell_exec('TestingStuff.py ' . $var1);

echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
```

`TestingStuff.py`

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(sys.argv[1])
```

**Demo**

[image]

**Explanation**

1. We will start with the Python script. The goal is, that the script prints the first argument passed to it - without running into the "IndexError: list index out of range" error.

   - `python TestingStuff.py 123` we want the output `123`.
2. In Python the arguments passed to the script reside in `sys.argv`. It's a list. `sys.argv[0]` is always the script name itself (here `TestingStuff.py`). Using the example from above `sys.argv[1]` is now 123.
3. Handling the edge cases: "no argument" given.

   - `python TestingStuff.py`

   This will result in an "IndexError: list index out of range" error, because you are trying to access a list element, which is not there. `sys.argv[0]` is the script name and `sys.argv[1]` is not set, but you are trying to print it and BAM goes the error. To avoid the error and only print the first argument, we need to make sure, that the list `sys.argv` contains more than one element (more than the script name). That's why i've added `if len(sys.argv) > 1:`.

   That means: print the first argument only, if the list has more than 1 argument.
4. Now we can test the Python script standalone - with and without arguments.
   And switch over to the PHP script.
5. The goal is to execute the Python script from PHP.

   PHP provides several ways to execute a script, there are for instance exec(), passthru(), shell_exec(), system(). Here we are using shell_exec(). shell_exec() returns the output of the script or command we run with it.

   In other words: if you run `$result = shell_exec('php -v');`, you'll get the PHP version lines in $result.

   Here we are executing the Python script `TestingStuff.py` and add an argument, which is `$var1`. It's a string and added via concatenation to the string given to shell_exec(). The `$result` is echoed. I wrapped pre-tags around it, because i thought this is executed in the web/browser context. If you are using the scripts only on the CLI, you might drop the pre-tags.

**Execution flow**

- the PHP script is executed
- shell_exec() executes the Python script
- shell_exec() returns the output of the Python script as `$result`
- $result is printed by PHP via echo

Comment: Nothing outputs. Is there any way I can specifically reference the php file in my python script?

Comment: Throw a `print(sys.argv)` in, to see the full argument list on Python side. I've added echo $result to the PHP side to display the output of shell_exec.

Comment: No change. When printing `print(sys.argv)` I get: `['C:/actual/TestingStuff.py']`

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing but it's very important that I learn how to do this soon

Comment: I'm not sure, why it doesn't work on your side. This is working fine here.. see image. The pre tags are not really needed, i thought it's for web context.

Comment: Wait! Do you mean to say that the output is due to `echo` in PHP and not due to `print` in python?

Comment: Sure, shell_exec() executes the python script (via python TestingStuff.py) and returns the output ($result)... The output is generated by Python, that's the print(...)

Comment: Oops, my bad. I understood that now! Nice answer.

Comment: I have a Python file written in IDLE and a PHP file written in Notepad++. When I run the Python file, to print `sys.argv[1]` the index is out of range

Comment: That's strange, but an issue of the execution environment, i think. That's why i posted the image with "python TestingStuff.py FooBar" to have a standalone test of the arg output. And then start to exec this from PHP.

Comment: @JensA.Koch What do you mean by 'FooBar'? Where do you suggest I insert this?

Comment: In the example provided "FooBar" is an example argument, passed to "TestingStuff.py". Means, you can test, if sys.argv[1] is printed. In other words: just execute "TestingStuff.py withWhateverYouLikeAsAnArgument" to test printing. And this Test makes sure, you don't run into the IndexError. Also to make sure that the Python script runs standalone...